# Sending parameters to report from Java code

Tags: jasper-reports

I need to send a timestamp value as parameter from java to *JR* report. I tried the following code but I'm getting a **blank report**.

My JRXML File:
`

`
The report works fine with normal date parameter but fails to display with Time-stamp value.

My Java code :
`

I tried various values of timestamp Ex: (new java.sql.Timestamp(2013-02-27) but it is not working.

Comment: Hey Somehow couldnt reply on chat, could you plz post the question and post link here.! :(

Comment: I got the answer it was because of the parameter mis match. Thanks anyways. Do you have any idea of how to display the chart in the JSP. I'm just getting the report data

Comment: hmmm what frontend technology do u use??

Comment: JSP / Servlet . I generate the report and print using out stream but the chart image is missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

`new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse("2012-01-01");`

Simply putting:

`new Date(2012-01-01);`

would give definitely wrong date, probably EPOCH start date.

Ensure it's `MM` not `mm` when parsing your date for month. See [SimpleDateFormat javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

**EDIT**

See the image. The date your default values will generate is around 1970.
Hence your **`Between`** Condition will get all the values between 1970 to **Today**.

[image]

**EDIT : 2**

In *my opinion* You are setting wrong parameter in Table's datasource.

Instead of setting From_Date & To_Date from `Fields` set them as parameter from the main report itself.

Refer Image.

[image]

Comment: I'm getting error when i use new SimpleDateFormatter("yyyy-MM-dd").parse("2012-01-01");.


`Unknow Class : simpleDateFormatter: line 1
 @ line 183, column 22. calculator_smbdbFinalR_1361340488268_509991: 303: unable to resolve class SimpleDateFormatter   @ line 303, column 22. calculator_smbdbFinalR_1361340488268_509991: 423: unable to resolve class SimpleDateFormatter`

Comment: hey sadagopan, i dont see your jrxml.
Could plz post in your question.

Comment: Hi Indyaah . I have uploaded my JRXML file . Please help to resolve it .Thanks

Comment: which iReport/JasperReport Studio version are you using?

Comment: could you join chat Sadagopan?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25073/discussion-between-sadagopan-iyengar-and-indyaah)